# how to hide a div starting the code, angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using this code to check the Internet end user.

```
myapp.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
  $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.online = false;
    });
  }, false);
  $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.online = true;
    });
  }, false); 
});
```

I have a div on my page that way. By default it is as display:none;

```
<div id="connec_failed">...</div>
```

**How do I display this div starting the code that checks the internet if the result return false?**

**How to hide the div again when the result returns true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-hide`: if `online`

```
<div id="connec_failed" ng-hide="online">...</div>
```